# Disable list box selection in D&D

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm using list box and when you click on item on it you see that blue line is marked on the value of the list box ,I want to disable it that you cannot mark value of the list box and 
copy paste it

I tried with IsSelected="False"  without success...

```
<ListBox x:Name="seus" IsSelected="False"  Height="115" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Use}" SelectionChanged="listbox_SelectionChanged" AllowDrop="True" PreviewDrop="ListBox_PreviewDrop" />
```

This is the event for list box

```
private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBox)
    {
        var listBox = sender as ListBox;
        if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            if (listBox.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var mySelectedItem = listBox.SelectedItem as User;
                if (mySelectedItem != null)
                {
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, mySelectedItem.Name, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return;
}
```

Comment: Just between the lines, else return; is a redundant control flow jump statement in this case. U can simply remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off the selection is indeed a bit tricky. But adding an ItemContainerStyle does it:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I know that's only half the way. It does not turn off copy/paste.